# Pair two lists in inverse order

Tags: python

What I want to do is to choose one item in list A and another one in list B, pair them like:

```
A[0]+B[n], A[1]+B[n-1],.....,A[n]+B[1]
```

I use two `for` loops but it doesn't work:

```
class Solution(object):
def plusOne(self, digits):
    sum=0
    for j in range(len(digits)-1,0,-1) :
        for i in range(0,len(digits),1):
            sum=sum+digits[i]*pow(10,j)
    return sum+1
```

I inputted `[1,2,3]` and what I want to get is `124`,
but I got `661`.

**Edit:**

Sorry, the example I gave above is not so clear.

Let us think about `A[1,2,3]` and `B[6,5,4]`.

I want output `[5,7,9]`, because `5` is `1+4`, `7` is `2+5`, `9` is `3+6`

Comment: You only need one loop..

Comment: You talk about two lists A and B, but in your sample input only mention one list.

Comment: There's also no 10^n in your explanation, so it doesn't fit your code.

Comment: Sorry, I use am wrong example.

Comment: That us think about two lists: A[1,2,3],B[6,5,4]. What should I do if I want to output 579?(5 is 1+4,7 is 2+5,9 is 3+6)

Comment: updated for your second request, kindly check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You only need one loop if you want to search in same list back and forth or different list with same length (i and len(lst)-1-i).
2. Try not use build-ins such as `sum`, `list`, `tuple`, `str`, `int` as variable names, it will give you some nasty result in some case.

   ```
   class Solution(object):
       def plusOne(self, digits):
           sum_val = 0
           for i in range(len(digits)):
               sum_val += digits[i]*pow(10, len(digits)-1-i)
           return sum_val+1

   sol = Solution()
   dig = [1, 2, 3]
   print(sol.plusOne(dig))
   ```

Output:

> ```
> 124
> ```

for `A = [1, 2, 3]` and `B = [6, 5, 4]`.

You can use a list comprehension:

```
res = [A[i]+B[len(A)-i-1] for i in range(len(A))]
```

Or the `zip()` function and a list comprehension:

```
res = [a+b for (a, b) in zip(A, reversed(B))]
```

Result:

```
[5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you, I know how to solve this kind of problems right now

Comment: No problem, downvote is kind of western humor, take it ez.

Comment: HAHAHA.....this is the second time for me to use western website to ask questions

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is turn a list of digits into the according number (and add `1`). You can [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) the reversed list in order to pair a digit with its appropriate power of `10`:

```
digits = [1, 2, 3]
sum(10**i * y for i, y in enumerate(digits[::-1])) + 1
# 124
```

You can apply that to your other example as follows, using `zip`:

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [6,5,4]
sum(10**i * (x+y) for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(B, A[::-1])))
# 579
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without a loop:

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [6,5,4]

C = list(map(sum,zip(A,B[::-1]) ))

print(C)
```

`zip()` - creates pairs of all elements of iterables, you feed it `A` and `B` reversed (via slicing). Then you sum up each pair and create a list from those sums.

`map( function, iterable)` - applies the function to each element of the iterable

`zip()` works when both list have the same length, else you would need to leverage [itertools.zip_longest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with a defaultvalue of `0`.

```
K = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
P = list(map(sum, zip_longest(K,C,fillvalue=0)))

print(P)
```

Output:

```
[5, 7, 9]   # zip of 2 same length lists A and B reversed
[6, 9, 12, 4, 5, 6]   # ziplongest for no matter what length lists
```